# Making a Facebook login button android app page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am making a facebook login page android app, just with login button. In my this example after login the cancel method runs instead of onSccess.

Here is my code..

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
 private TextView info;
 private LoginButton loginButton;
 private CallbackManager callbackManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);


    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken access_token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            info.setText("welcome"  +profile.getName());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}

}
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Which SDK are you using? Can you reproduce this behavior with any of the samples which come with the SDK?

Comment: which sdk you are using? and put some error logcat.